# Azure Functions: Exception while executing function: Functions.x <--- Result: Failure Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, virtualenv

I ran into this error after uploading a local Python function with:

```
func azure functionapp publish $APP_NAME --build-native-deps
```

The solution that I used to fix it is below in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the issue was that I was building a Python 3.6 environment, but using a Python 3.7 virtualenv.

Running:

```
/usr/bin/python3.6 -m venv .venv
```

To create the virtual environment before creating the function fixed the issue for me.